# How to use LWUIT with NetBeans IDE 7.1.2?

Tags: netbeans, java-me, lwuit, java-wireless-toolkit

I am having some confusion as how to integrate LWUIT ver 1.5 with NetBeans IDE 7.1.2.

I am using a tutorial (http://lwuit.java.net/tutorial/hello.html); the url of which I found in Stack Overflow. In the tutorial somewhere it says that select "Sun Java(TM) Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 for CLDC or Sprint Wireless Toolkit 3.2 Powered by Sun Java Technology" for the Emulator Platform.

However in my NetBeans IDE there is only one item in the combobox for Emulator Platform and it's "CLDC Oracle Java(Tm) Platform Micro Edition SDK 3.0.5".

Please advise what is going wrong. Is it happening because NetBeans is not installed properly or it is for something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong, Micro Edition SDK 3 should be OK, it's just a newer version of the toolkit mentioned in LWUIT tutorial.

- The version change is explained in java.net blog entry [Goodbye WTK, hello Java ME SDK!](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/terrencebarr/archive/2008/10/goodbye_wtk_hel.html)

  > For years the Sun Java Wireless Toolkit for CLDC (WTK) has been the reference tool for developing mobile applications and emulating mobile platforms on the desktop...
  >
  > However, it also suffered from a few weaknesses...
  >
  > So it was time for a radical update. Say goodbye to WTK and hello to the Java ME SDK!
  >
  > ...What does this mean for developers?
  >
  > The Java ME SDK is a much improved tool all-around. It is based on the very capable Netbeans framework so it is more easily extensible and more portable than before. It incorporates all major Java ME platforms (mass-market mobile phones, smart phones, and Blu-ray) into a single tool. The Java ME emulation is now much accurate as phoneME (and it's commercial counterparts) is used in millions of devices today...

If for some reason you will still need an older version WTK, there is a link provided to where to download it from at [Stack Overflow 'wtk' tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wtk/info).

Comment: Thanks for the reply gnat.So WTK has been replaced with more powerful Java ME SDK and Java ME SDK comes integrated with the latest release of NetBeans 7.1.2.While googling, i came across a link (https://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/java_me_sdk_3_01) which seems to have answered all my queries...I would like to thank everybody for all the replies..

Answer (score 0):

Download the Sun java wireless toolkit (will prolly be called something else now, since Oracle has taken over Sun). Install it. After this, it should appear in your netbeans.

Comment: yes Nikhil i have downloaded the latest Sun Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2_01 for CLDC and also installed it successfully.After installation i find that its a separate application in itself with its IDE and all...But i want it to integrated in the NetBeans IDE itself just like it has been mentioned in the tutorial  http://lwuit.java.net/tutorial/hello.html....

Comment: yes..its pretty simple. Right click your J2me project in netbeans. Goto properties and then browse around a bit. Go to the section where you have the JAVA ME emulator mentioned. Look for something like..add new emulator..or something of that sort. WTK should be automatically added to that list (which shows which all emulators are currently available on your system). Choose WTK and start building!